# If-else - If found a value with bs4 ... Else

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm currently trying to do a mix between HTML and Python. My idea is:

```
If I find a value in this HTML:

   Then run this method

Else:

    Run this other method.
```

Basically I have

```
soup = soup(r.content, "lxml")
findKey = soup.find('div', {'class': 'TalkingHand'})['data-key']
```

so far and what I want to do is to make it like if I find a any value or this element in the HTML then I supposed to do a method inside my program which we can call *MethodFound* but if we don't find this element in the HTML then we should do something else: we can call it *DoNothing*

I'm stuck at the if statement where I don't really know where to start.

```
If(findKey == ..... <-- I dont know really)...
```

Comment: Thank you for the edit :) Appreciate it!

Comment: If the item is not there bs4 will throw an exception just catch it. no need to if else.

Comment: Oh. I tried that and I got expectipn ```TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable```. Like how do I in that case write a exception like that  in a If else state :D?

Comment: @WelnThis check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch the exception that bs4 will throw when the element is not there. Here is an example.

```
try:
    soup = soup(r.content, "lxml")
    findKey = soup.find('div', {'class': 'TalkingHand'})['data-key']

    # Do stuff with the found key
except AttributeError:
    # Key wasn't found do stuff
    pass
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank you so much!